# Ada - Deallocation from a Heterogenous List

Tags: memory-management, ada, circular-list

I'm creating a heterogenous circular linked list through inheritance. As a dynamically allocated data type, I need some form of deallocation, so I initially thought of `Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation`. Unfortunately, with the way that my access type works because the root Element is tagged and because I want to be able to use the same pointer type to access any object of the hierarchy, the following code snippet will not compile.

```
type Element is tagged private;
type ElementPtr is access all Element'Class;

-- fully define Element

procedure Free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(Element, ElementPtr);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for alternate forms of deallocation that I can use to free the memory used by an object of any inherited Element type pointed to by an ElementPtr? Thanks!

Comment: For future reference: when you say "will not compile", it would help us if you added the actual error message to your question

Comment: Why not build it on top of Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Doubly_Linked_Lists and avoid the use of access-to-object types completely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Element` and `Element'Class` are different types,
and you try to instantiate `Unchecked_Deallocation` with mismatching types.
Try instantiating with `Element'Class` instead:

```Ada
procedure Free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(Element'Class, ElementPtr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking of Element'Class as just an extension of Element, and that was my problem.

Comment: @OCDkirby It IS just an extension of Element, but Ada allows you to distinguish between the base class (Element) and the "class wide type" (Element and all its subclasses) : your Free (per question) was specifically restricted to the base class while the pointer was class-wide.

Comment: @OCDkirby — One of the deficiencies of a lot of OOP implementations is the tendency to confuse and conflate "this type" and "this type, and anything descended from it" (certainly WRT parameters). Ada avoids this by having `X` refer explicitly to that type, and `X'Class` refer to "this, and anything descended."